# What color is the Sky on other Planets?

Tags: planet

On Earth, the sky is blue.

What color would the sky be on other planets in our solar system? What about outside the solar system? Are there planets with purple skies, or green skies? Or are the all just blue?

Comment: We have seen pictures from Mars and Venus. They aren't blue:-)

Comment: [On Mars, the sky is red and the sunset is blue](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/10771/5264)

Comment: [Terrestrial Exoplanet Skies – I've Built a Visual Sky Chart. Is it Accurate?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/24048/7982)

Comment: Also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/24804/do-the-gases-in-the-earths-atmosphere-affect-the-color-of-a-lunar-eclipse

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24108/why-would-mars-sky-appear-blue-at-dawn-and-dusk-but-red-during-the-middle-of-t

Answer (score 2):

The color you can see in the sky depends on two things, first the color (if you want to be more specific, the emission spectra of the light of the star) of the light shining, this is the Sun in our case (but may be another star in order to answer your question about outside the solar system), and second depends on the chemical components of the atmosphere of the planet in question, because this atmosphere is the reason for what is called the absorption lines.

Absorption light is something like that, if you have white light and a gas with green absorption lines, then after crossing the gas the light will turn the opposite of green, I don't know what color that is.

In conclusion if our atmosphere changes (for some unknown reason) here on planet Earth, then the color of the sky is going to change.

Comment: Absorption plus scattering of different types plus refraction. Based on absorption only we would have a sun white sky dome here on earth. But correct is with a change in atmosphere we might see change in colours.

Comment: I have to comment that the sky on Earth varies considerably in color. It can change with season, time of day, atmospheric contaminants, etc. However, I guess that most people would consider the sky to be blue.