# Atmosphere colour from orbit

Tags: exoplanet, planetary-atmosphere

I know a few different resources for determining the colour of a world's sky depending on its star and atmospheric pressure, but I haven't been able to find anything for how it would look from space (same thing for clouds). Does anyone know any charts, calculators, etc. for this, or even just the basics?

Comment: there might be some helpful information in answers or links at [What color is the Sky on other Planets?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29247/7982) and [Terrestrial Exoplanet Skies – I've Built a Visual Sky Chart. Is it Accurate?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/24048/7982)